# VSTS. Reference concatenated variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I was wondering if it possible to reference concatenated variable name1 and name2 as part of build process? Suppose I'd like to create a resource group called winning-development. Where name1=winning-, and name2=development.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special to concatenate variables.

Let's say you had `foo` = 'hello' and `bar` = 'world'.

`$(foo)$(bar)` = 'helloworld'

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Can I do something like [$(foo)$(bar)del1charactertotheright], so I can have helloworl without last character d?

Comment: No. There aren't string manipulation functions like you'd find in an ARM template.

Comment: Except that a literal and a variable adds a space
rmdir foot$(toe) - where $toe) equals Big

results in  
rmdir foot Big (note space)

Not in 
rmdir footBig (no space)

Comment: @DavidV.Corbin That is not the case in my experience.

Comment: Daniel - goot to hear from you, it has been quite some time.... So, it looks like something on my end... will have to dig deeper. Just getting confirmation that it does not happen to everyone/all the time is quite valuable....